# Wrong year value from Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)

Tags: java

I am get wrong output for the below code.

```
class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String dateStr = "May 11, 2019 11:35:34 AM";
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY HH:mm:ss a");
            try{
                Date d1 = format.parse(dateStr);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(d1);
                System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                System.out.println(Calendar.YEAR);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

O/P
2018

Expected O/P
2019

Comment: Use `yyyy` not `YYYY`

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: When I run your code on my computer, `d1` is Mon Dec 31 11:35:34 CET 2018. Uppercase `YYYY` is for week-based year and only useful with a week number. Lacking a week number it seems that `SimpleDateFormat` picks the first day of week 1. And this happens to fall in 2018.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use with lower case `y`, as bellow:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
```

Note that lower/upper case change the result

```
| Letter | Date/Time component |
| y      | Year                |
| Y      | Week year           |
| m      | Minute              |
| M      | Month in year       |
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Calendars. An ISO week date and other one Gregorian. The ISO week date has 52 or 53 whole weeks, meaning it would not have normal 365/366 days as we know based on leap year or not but 365/371 days (365+ 1 week). yyyy is the normal calendar year we know.

Alternatively, you can use GregorianCalendar in place of Calendar as below to get same result for either YYYY or yyyy -

```
GregorianCalendar gregcal = new GregorianCalendar();
gregcal.setTime(d1);
System.out.println(gregcal.getWeekYear());
```

Comment: Just a slight adjustment: A week based year has either 52 weeks = **364** days or 53 weeks = (correct) 371 days.